# Magento - undefined variable this in block template

Tags: php, magento

I am making a simple magento block and a template for it.

In my custom module I have a config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <AAA_Recentproducts>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </AAA_Recentproducts>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <recentproducts>
        <class>AAA_Recentproducts_Block</class>
      </recentproducts>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

And this is my Block

```
<?php
class AAA_Recentproducts_Block_Recentproducts extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
  public function getRecentProducts() {
    $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
                    ->setPageSize(5);
    return $products;
  }
}
```

And finally my template file:

```
<?php
$products = $this­->getRecentProducts();
//$products = [];
?>

<div id="product_list">
  <h1>Recent Products</h1>
  <?php if (is_array($products) && count($products)) { ?>
    <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
      <div>
    product
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

The error I get is: `2015-11-02T08:53:55+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: this­  in /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/smartwave/granada/template/recentproducts/recentproducts.phtml on line 2`

Does anyone have an idea why this error occurs?

Comment: Can you show your layout XML?  My guess is you're not applying the correct block or template there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `$this` if you're not inside a class. You have to create an instance of `AAA_Recentproducts_Block_Recentproducts` and call the function on that object.

```
$object = new AAA_Recentproducts_Block_Recentproducts();
$products = $object->getRecentProducts();
```

I wouldn't recommend the variable name `$object`, but i can't think of a better one right now. You get the point.

Comment: You CAN use `$this` inside a template within Magento. `$this` refers to the block instance.

Comment: in all tutorials they use the $this instance, but somehow it doesnt work. If I initiate the class myself it works

Comment: Can you post your layout XML Safari?

Comment: I have not changed the layout XML.

Comment: You need to tell Magento to use your block with the template - have you done this in an admin {{ }} call?  Can you provide this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the layout xml file, you can call the block using the below code

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('recentproducts/recentproducts');
$products = $block->getRecentProducts();
```

Use this code in your phtml file

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem came from `$this­->getTest();` having a strange hidden character between "s-"

You should be able to use this because of fetchView's include, in Block_Template.